# PCRE Regex: Is it possible to check within only the first X characters of a string for a match

Tags: regex, pcre

**PCRE Regex: Is it possible for Regex to check for a pattern match within *only* the first X characters of a string, ignoring other parts of the string beyond that point?**

## My Regex:

I have a Regex:

```
/\S+V\s*/
```

This checks the string for non-whitespace characters whoich have a trailing 'V' and then a whitespace character or the end of the string.

This works. For example:

**Example A:**

> ```
>  SEBSTI FMDE OPORV AWEN STEM students into STEM 
>
> // Match found in 'OPORV' (correct)
> ```

**Example B:**

> ```
>  ARKFE SSETE BLMI EDSF BRNT CARFR (name removed) Academy Networking Event 
>       
> //Match not found (correct).
> ```

Re: The capitalised text each letter and the letters placement has a meaning in the source data. This is followed by generic info for humans to read ("Academy Networking Event", etc.)

## My Issue:

It can theoretically occur that sometimes there are names that involve roman numerals such as:

**Example C:**

> ```
>  ARKFE SSETE BLME CARFR Academy IV Networking Event 
>       
> //Match found (incorrect).
> ```

I would like my Regex above to only check the first X characters of the string.

Can this be done in PCRE Regex itself? I can't find any reference to length counting in Regex and I suspect this can't easily be achieved. String lengths are completely arbitary. (We have no control over the source data).

## Intention:

```
/\S+V\s*/{check within first 25 characters only}
```

> ```
>  ARKFE SSETE BLME CARFR Academy IV Networking Event 
>                          ^
>                          \-  Cut off point. Not found so far so stop. 
>
> //Match not found (correct).
> ```

## Workaround:

The Regex is in PHP and my current solution is to cut the string in PHP, to only check the first X characters, typically the first 20 characters, but I was curious if there was a way of doing this within the Regex without needing to manipulate the string directly in PHP?

```
$valueSubstring = substr($coreRow['value'],0,20); /* first 20 characters only */
$virtualCount = preg_match_all('/\S+V\s*/',$valueSubstring);
```

Comment: Your "workaround" sounds like the simplest way to do it and it is probably what anyone would recommend. Finding a way to do it using only a regular expression would probably make a regular expression more difficult to understand.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón absolutely, but I was curious as I have never ever seen any Regex reference to searching only a sub-part of a string.

Comment: If you insist, I guess you could use a positive lookbehind to match up to 25-n characters before your match (with length n).

Comment: What about "ARKFE SSETE BLMEV CARFR Academy IV Networking Event" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your pattern after X chars and skip the whole string, else, match your pattern. So, if X=25:

```php
^.{25,}\S+V.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\S+V\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dg6LWT/1). *Details*:

- `^.{25,}\S+V.*(*SKIP)(*F)` - start of string, 25 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, then one or more non-whitespaces and `V`, and then the rest of the string, the match is failed and skipped
- `|` - or
- `\S+V\s*` - match one or more non-whitespaces, `V` and zero or more whitespace chars.

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks. I never knew about the `(*F)` functionality.

Comment: Curiously, the Regex link shows 600 steps, but I would have hoped that after the 25th character, the steps would abort (with approx 60 steps)

Comment: It fails to find a V ending when there are "roman numerals" further down the line.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That is the intention. I only want to look for V in the first X characters of the string, in this case, 25

Comment: @Martin The pattern is more a schematic, PoC one. you may further improve it, for example, in the skip part, you need not match all non-whitespaces, so use `^.{25,}\SV.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\S+V\s*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your newer pattern matches with only 300 steps which I will take as the best route for this exploration. This query was more for curiosity rather than any code efficiency but it is interesting to find some Regex escaping clauses `(*F)` I wasn't aware of. 
Thanks

Comment: For some reason, while this works correctly on Regex101, using [this in PHP code](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/471ea61827aaea2ea4aee2941b24265f1c240e8c) it returns a match for `IV` outside of the 25 chr limit. Do you have any clues why this works on Regex101.com but not in sandbox PHP? Cheerrs

Comment: @Martin You are not testing correctly. See [this PHP demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b49ab1129c1658646e84d67afc1c49f49dc1b67)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ahhh, I had missed off the `/m` that fixed it. Thanks again for your advice `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to capture the end of the line after the first 25 characters in a lookahead and to check if it follows the eventual match of your subpattern:

```php
$pattern = '~^(?=.{0,25}(.*)).*?\K\S+V\b(?=.*\1)~m';
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/1oSwqQ/1)

details:

```
^ # start of the line

(?= # open a lookahead assertion
    .{0,25} # the twenty first chararcters
    (.*) # capture the end of the line
) # close the lookahead

.*? # consume lazily the characters

\K # the match result starts here

\S+V    # your pattern
\b      # a word boundary (that matches between a letter and a white-space
        # or the end of the string)

(?=.*\1) # check that the end of the line follows with a reference to
         # the capture group 1 content.
```

Note that you can also write the pattern in a more readable way like this:

```
$pattern = '~^
    (*positive_lookahead: .{0,20} (?<line_end> .* ) )
    .*?    \K    \S+ V \b
    (*positive_lookahead: .*? \g{line_end} )   ~xm';
```

(The alternative syntax `(*positive_lookahead: ...)` is available since PHP 7.3)

Answer (score -2):

Any V ending in the first 25 positions

```
^.{1,24}V\s
```

See [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Dg6LWT/1)

Any word ending in V in the first 25 positions

```
^.{1,23}[A-Z]V\s
```

Comment: I need to find a V preceeded by a non-whitespace character and followed by a whitespace character, and only in the first part of the string. This matches the casing in any part of the string.

Comment: You will be only able to find a *single* match with this pattern. Searching within the first X chars implies there may be more than one match.

Comment: It doesn't, see link

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the line matches, as was asked.

Comment: Even then, your pattern is not the same as OP's. Your regex [matches](https://regex101.com/r/Dg6LWT/2), e.g. `1 V (ex)` which is not expected.

Comment: Better than missing one, I'd say. Still, added an improvement.